# cannot import name BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to use BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator operator but it gives me an import error.

Comment: Which version are you using? Maybe you are using Composer with Airflow 1.9.0 and based on the documentation, it's available since 1.10.0 https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/2920d047541c0c410e7db72c7ae81a6ee85bb08c

Answer (score 1):

from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator